# Changing the color of a progress bar dynamically in Odoo 16

Tags: javascript, odoo, progress-bar, odoo-16

I want to change the color of a progress bar that is in a one2many line in an Transient Model.
My idea was to create a custom widget from the progressbar widget and then add a method that gets the color value and the script changes the color.
The color value will be stored in a computed field that is invisible in the line.

So my first try was to create the custom widget, but that didn't work.

```
odoo.define('your_module_name.custom_progressbar', function (require) {
"use strict";

var field_registry = require('web.field_registry');
var FieldProgressBar = require('web.basic_fields').FieldProgressBar;

var CustomProgressBar = FieldProgressBar.extend({
    template: FieldProgressBar.prototype.template,
    // Your custom methods and properties here
});

field_registry.add('custom_progressbar', CustomProgressBar);

return CustomProgressBar;
```

});

I am not very good at Java coding, and the web was no help in that case.
The problem is that I get a message in the browser dev tools:

```
web.assets_backend.min.js:2970 Missing widget: CustomProgressBar for field of type integer
```

At this point, I have not tried to make the part with the colors until the original widget is shown in my view.

and the widget is not shown.

And yes the .js is in manifast and will also run

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to inherit the [progress bar field](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/web/static/src/views/fields/progress_bar/progress_bar_field.js)

***Example:***

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { ProgressBarField } from "@web/views/fields/progress_bar/progress_bar_field";

export class CustomProgressBarField extends ProgressBarField {
    
}

registry.category("fields").add("custom_progressbar", CustomProgressBarField);
```

You can use a custom template as follows:

```js
CustomProgressBarField.template = "web.CustomProgressBarField";
```

To change field color based on a computed field, you can use the `t-attf-class` attribute:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">

    <t t-name="web.CustomProgressBarField" t-inherit="web.ProgressBarField" t-inherit-mode="primary" owl="1">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_progress')]/div" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="t-attf-class">{{ props.record.data.color_field < 5 ? 'bg-danger' : 'bg-primary' }} h-100</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </t>

</templates>
```

***Example2:***

Set progress bar background color based on color field and field name passed through field options:

***progress_bar_field.js***

```
export class CustomProgressBarField extends ProgressBarField {}

CustomProgressBarField.template = 'chn_event_availability_manager.custom_progressbar_template';

CustomProgressBarField.props = {
    ...ProgressBarField.props,
    colorField: { type: String, optional: true },  // Hinzufügen der colorField-Option
};

CustomProgressBarField.extractProps = ({ attrs }) => {
    const parentProps = ProgressBarField.extractProps({ attrs });  // Extrahieren Sie die Eigenschaften von der übergeordneten Methode
    return {
        ...parentProps,  // Fügen Sie die extrahierten Eigenschaften von der übergeordneten Methode hinzu
        colorField: attrs.options.color_field,  // Extrahieren Sie die neue Eigenschaft 'colorField'
    };
};
registry.category("fields").add("custom_progressbar", CustomProgressBarField);
```

***custom_progressbar_template.xml***

```xml
<t t-name="chn_event_availability_manager.custom_progressbar_template" t-inherit="web.ProgressBarField" t-inherit-mode="primary" owl="1">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_progress')]/div" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="t-att-style">'width: min(' + 100 * state.currentValue / state.maxValue + '%, 100%)' + ';background-color: ' + (props.record.data[props.colorField] or '#007bff') + ' !important'</attribute>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

***Update:***

To use a color passed through the field options use `props.colorField` instead of `props.record.data[props.colorField]` in the style expression

Comment: Thank you very much! The part with not showing the widget is solved now, but I have problems getting the colour in the progress bar.

I will post my code in the next reply.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my latest code:

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { ProgressBarField } from "@web/views/fields/progress_bar/progress_bar_field";

console.log("Run CustomProgressBarField");

export class CustomProgressBarField extends ProgressBarField {
    template = 'chn_event_availability_manager.custom_progressbar_template';

    constructor() {
           super(...arguments);
           this.color = this.getColorValue(this.props);
           console.log("Run constructor");
           console.log('Color:', this.color);
    }

   renderElement() {
        super.renderElement(...arguments);
        this.el.querySelector('.o_progressbar .o_progress .o_progress_bar').style.backgroundColor = this.color;
        const colorFieldInput = this.el.querySelector('.o_field_widget[name="color_field"]');
        if (colorFieldInput) {
            colorFieldInput.addEventListener('change', this._onColorFieldChange.bind(this));
        }
    }

    _onColorFieldChange(event) {
        this.color = event.target.value;
        this.renderElement();
    }

    getColorValue(p) {
       return p.colorField || '#007bff';  // Standardfarbe ist Blau
    }
}

CustomProgressBarField.props = {
    ...ProgressBarField.props,
    colorField: { type: String, optional: true },  // Hinzufügen der colorField-Option
};

CustomProgressBarField.extractProps = ({ attrs }) => {
    const parentProps = ProgressBarField.extractProps({ attrs });  // Extrahieren Sie die Eigenschaften von der übergeordneten Methode
    return {
        ...parentProps,  // Fügen Sie die extrahierten Eigenschaften von der übergeordneten Methode hinzu
        colorField: attrs.options.color_field,  // Extrahieren Sie die neue Eigenschaft 'colorField'
    };
};

registry.category("fields").add("custom_progressbar", CustomProgressBarField);
```

Now the problem I am trying to solve is that the function:

RenderElement() is not executed, I do not know why, so the color is not transferred to the progress bar.

But I am getting the correct value in the constructor().

of the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="custom_progressbar_template" inherit_id="web.ProgressBarField" name="Custom Progress Bar">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_progress']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="t-att-style">`'background-color: ' + (record.color_field ? record.color_field : '#007bff')`</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

and the css to change the color:

```
.custom_progressbar .o_progressbar .o_progress .bg-primary {
    background-color: #007bff !important; /* Default color is blue */
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Is there any good explanation for the js. part in odoo 16, thats not easy to understand the framework.

thanks

Comment: The `owl` component has the `render` function

Comment: So I have to get the owl? Sorry, I am learning it at the moment 
Do you maybe have an example?

Comment: In your code above you're defining a new function named `renderElement`. `ProgressBarField` extends `Component` which has a `render` function. `owl` is a custom component framework

Comment: I have already defined the renderElement function.

Comment: But you try to override it ! Make sure it is defined in the parent class

Comment: Sorry i dont understanding how that works.

Comment: Did you try to use `props.record.data.color_field`  in style expression?

Comment: Is it possible that we are talking about different things?
I am not sure that my idea is the best way to get the result, I just want to set the colour of the progress bar to the hex colour value that is in options.

Comment: The last thing I checked was that the function, I dont know if the function works correctly but the function is never called, I tested this in the browser tools with a breakpoint.
I do not understand why such simple things like changing the color of a field is so difficult to do in odoo, why is there no out of the box function for each element?

Comment: Odoo should update the background color when the field value changes. Check my answer, I will update it with an example

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).